# How to authenticate session inside class based view django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django

I am trying to convert my function-based views to class-based views. Here I ran into a problem.

I don't know whether the user is logged in or not. I can't call the user.is_authenticated inside my class-based view.

My Code:

```
class UserLoginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
        if user is not None:
            login(request=self.request, user=user)
            print('Login Successfull')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print('Login Failed')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

How can I check whether the user is already logged in and send him directly to the home page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your requirement, you want to authenticate a user and send them to the home page after logged-in in a class-based view.

Here is what we can do. We can use the LoginRequiredMixin in your class-based **home page view** to help us to check is a user logged-in. If a user is not logged-in, they will be redirected to a login page we specified. Otherwise, execute the view normally and the user will be free to access the home page.

Example:

In **views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin):  # Add the LoginRequiredMixin 
    template_name = 'index.html'
    login_url = '/login/'  # Replace '/login/' with your login URL, an un-logged-in user will be redirect to this URL
```

One thing must care about while using the LoginRequiredMixin is the ordering.

Mostly we put the LoginRequiredMixin in the first position of inheritance if our class-based view inherited multiple classes. Because it makes sure the user is logged-in before the view does anything further for the user.

```
class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, ClassA, ClassB):
    pass
```

You can get more information about LoginRequiredMixin in this [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)